# Firebase Functions unable to run HelloWorld example with Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I try to call the most basic https function from unity, but I always get an internal error.

I deployed the function and it works when called by the browser:
https://us-central1-infinite-space-rpg.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld

Node.js code:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

unity code:

```cs
        FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance;

        var func = functions.GetHttpsCallable("helloWorld");
        func.CallAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread((response) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("result: " + response.Result.Data.ToString());
            });
```

This is the faulted error response I get:
[image]

In the firebase dashboard I can see that the function gets called and it also completes without an error.

So the setup should be fine, but the "one or more errors occurred(INTERNAL) does not give any hint on what might be the issue.

Permissions should also be fine, all users can invoke the function.

I really hope that someone has an idea!

Comment: check the suggestions mentioned in this [github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/415)

Answer (score 0):

also tried the exact sample from firebase with the same error.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

I`m now stuck with this since 2 days, is there a better place to ask such a specific question, maybe a firebase support forum?